# Finding the income tax based on marital status and income - java

Tags: java

so my program calculates the income tax based on your marital status and income, its a class assignment and the teacher wants us to do it a certain way which is why i have constants defined by final and other things. Anyway I compiled my program and get no syntax errors however when i run the program the calculations are off.

For example when I input my marital status as single and then my income as 10000 it gives me the value 1000 when it should be 1100.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tax
{ 
public static void main(String[] args)
{

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  double tax = 0, taxIncome = 0;
  final double FIRST_SINGLE_TAX = .10;
  final double FIRST_MARRIED_TAX = .10;
  final double SECOND_SINGLE_TAX = .15;
  final double SECOND_SINGLE_VALUE = 800;
  final double SECOND_MARRIED_TAX = .15;
  final double SECOND_MARRIED_VALUE = 1600;
  final double THIRD_SINGLE_TAX = .25;
  final double THIRD_SINGLE_VALUE = 4400;
  final double THIRD_MARRIED_TAX = .25;
  final double THIRD_MARRIED_VALUE = 8800;

  System.out.print("Enter your marital status (single or married): ");
  String status = keyboard.nextLine();

  if(!status.equalsIgnoreCase("single") && !status.equalsIgnoreCase("married")) 
  {
     System.out.println("-- illegal marital status --");
     System.exit(0);
  }
  else 
  {
     System.out.print("Enter your taxable income: "); 
     taxIncome = keyboard.nextDouble();
  }

  if (status.equals("single"))

        if (taxIncome >= 0  && taxIncome <= 8000)
        {
           tax = taxIncome * FIRST_SINGLE_TAX;
        }
        else if (taxIncome > 8000 && taxIncome <= 32000)
        {
           tax = (SECOND_SINGLE_VALUE + (taxIncome - 8000) * SECOND_SINGLE_TAX);
        }
        else if (taxIncome >= 32000)
        {
           tax = (THIRD_SINGLE_VALUE + (taxIncome - 32000) * THIRD_SINGLE_TAX);
        }
        else 
        {
        System.out.print(" -- illegal income --");
        }

  else if(status.equals("married"));

       if (taxIncome >= 0 && taxIncome <= 16000)
       {
          tax = taxIncome * FIRST_MARRIED_TAX;
       }
       else if (taxIncome > 16000 && taxIncome <= 64000)
       {
          tax = (SECOND_MARRIED_VALUE + (taxIncome - 16000) * SECOND_MARRIED_TAX);
       }
       else if (taxIncome >64000) 
       {
          tax = (THIRD_MARRIED_VALUE + (taxIncome - 64000) * THIRD_MARRIED_TAX); 
       }
       else 
       {
          System.out.print (" -- illegal income --");
       }

       System.out.printf("Your income tax is $%.2f", tax);

 }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Why do you think the correct value should be $1100? 0.1×10000=1000.

Answer (score 2):

A good advise for you as a new programmer:

```
(1) Learn how to use the debugger,
(2) learn how to put in break points and investigate local variables and
(3) learn how to add and investigate logs.
```

Once you've done that, you realize the problem is with this statement:

```java
else if(status.equals("married"));
```

you're basically terminating the else statement there meaning the else does nothing and therefore, your "tax" value is overwritten by this line:

```
tax = taxIncome * FIRST_MARRIED_TAX;
```

change the `else if` ... to wrap your next statements `{ }` and you'll be fine.

```java
//... (if condition)
else if (status.equals("married")) {
    if (taxIncome >= 0 && taxIncome <= 16000) {
        tax = taxIncome * FIRST_MARRIED_TAX;
    } else if (taxIncome > 16000 && taxIncome <= 64000) {
        tax = (SECOND_MARRIED_VALUE + (taxIncome - 16000) * SECOND_MARRIED_TAX);
    } else if (taxIncome > 64000) {
        tax = (THIRD_MARRIED_VALUE + (taxIncome - 64000) * THIRD_MARRIED_TAX);
    } else {
        System.out.print(" -- illegal income --");
    }
}
```